# Opening the external browser out of an RCP application opens Firefox instead of default browser on Linux.

Tags: eclipse, url, browser, rcp

When I open an external browser out of my RCP application using:

`PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport().getExternalBrowser().openURL(url)`

It opens up firefox instead of the system default browser (chrome) on Linux (Ubuntu). My default browser is set correctly via update-alternatives and links out of Eclipse actually open in Chrome. The mime type of text/html is also set to chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to be able to set this via jcontrol->advanced, farthest down but I cannot for the world get Cisco ASDM to open anything other than Firefox on my Fedora.